# allowing and banning cipher-suites apache2.2

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, ssl

There is a list of banned and recommended cipher-suites that I need to add to `ssl.conf` file, and I'm facing some problem when trying to configure it:

I need to ban all `ECDH*` and allow 15 cipher-suites starting with `ECDHE*`, such as `ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256`.

How to configure it to work?

Comment: What was done until now?

Comment: What do you mean? until now I didn't need to ban ECDH as written in the question...

Comment: downvoted for 0 research work.

Comment: I saw that each ECDHE* from the list should be written. However, I wanted to see if there's another solution because the list is long.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that you know the syntax of the config file but just don't want to fiddle around with the huge list of ciphers: a text editing problem.

The list of ECDHE* ciphers is given by the shell command

```
openssl ciphers | tr ":" "\n" | grep ^ECDHE | tr "\n" ":" | sed 's/:$//'
```

You didn't say what you wanted to do with ciphers whose names don't start with ECDH* but by changing the argument to *grep* in the above you can get any sort of cipher list you want and concatenate them in your text editor as needed.  So to get a list of AES ciphers but not the AES128* ones you'd say `^AES[^1]`

That said, there might still be some manual fiddling to do as the order of the ciphers in the list can be important.  You can, and probably should, specify that the server shall try the ciphers in the order that they are in the enabling list.